# How to fix ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, encoding, utf-8

I am getting the following error [ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)]

Here is the log...

```
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 318ms 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:  ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8): 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:       97:         <!-- <td><%= row.notes.gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></td> --> 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:       98:       </tr> 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:       99:     <% end %> 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:      100:   </tbody> 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:      101: </table> 
    Jan 09 23:29:19 burro app/web.1:      102:
```

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
<td><%= row.notes.force_encoding("utf-8") %></td>
    <!-- <td><%= row.notes.gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></td> -->
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have all these in the correct rb and erb files?

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>


config.encoding = "utf-8"

Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

@data.each do |sr|
    sr.notes = sr.notes.to_s.force_encoding("UTF-8")
  end
```

The data in the db is encrypted so I can't run a query on my MongoDB data to see what special character is causing the issue, when displaying records?

Comment: `config/application.rb` should consist `config.encoding = "utf8"`

Comment: Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8 these two shoul be on config with development or production .rb file

Comment: I have done both of your comments and no change?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

`config/application.rb` should consist

```
  config.encoding = "utf8"
```

Also in your environments file

in `config/environments/development.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb` should have

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

and

Also use the below in .rb file

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

`It tells ruby to interpret the source of the file as utf-8, even if it doesn't contain any non-ascii characters`

in that particular file

hope it will solve this problem

Comment: Using # encoding: utf-8 in my erb file was cause an error it needs to be <%# encoding: utf-8 %>

Comment: do not require this in erb but reuire it in .rb files

Comment: I have # encoding: utf-8 in my model .rb files, but not by controller files.

Comment: ok did you restart ? after change environment files or application

Comment: Yes I have. I also did everything you stated above? I don't undertand I haven't updated the app at it was working fine for a week.

Comment: which mongodb version you are using which gem you are using for mono db

Comment: gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'